# No sound with HDA-Intel

Tags: sound, alsa, hda-intel, pavucontrol

on a relatively old ASUS laptop, I initially replaced the original Windows Vista with Linux Mint 19.3 XFCE. However, since this was very tough, I have now switched to Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

As with Linux Mint, there is no sound with Xubuntu. The loudspeaker is "not available" in pavucontrol. The speaker channel is initially muted in the alsamixer, but when I switch to the unavailable loudspeaker in pavucontrol the speaker channel in alsamixer switches automatically to mute off. Nevertheless the loudspeaker keeps unavailable.

Now I did
`cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xfeb3c000 irq 27
lspci | grep -i audio
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
basename -s ".ko" $(find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name "*.ko"  | grep snd | grep via)
    snd-via82xx
    snd-hda-codec-via
    snd-via82xx-modem
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
    Codec: Analog Devices Generic`

Now I added the line in "alsa-base.conf":
options snd-hda-intel model = generic

and then

`sudo alsa force-reload
sudo alsactl store`

Now the sound output worked! But after a restart, again no sound comes out. Now I tried all combinations with options snd-hda-intel model = xxxxx probe_mask = xxx but they also do not work. No sound anymore.

I know that others have had the same problem, but I didn't find any way to fix it.
Could someone help me?